# Phonegap Build API with CURL php

Tags: php, cordova, curl, phonegap

I'm trying to connect my account with [PHONEGAP REST API](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/developer-api/) by implementing CURL with laravel framework. Somehow I could do things with GET but never done with [POST and PUT](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/developer-api/write/). Is there anything wrong with my code? here's my example for uploading:

**App\Http\Controllers\BuildApiController@testBuild:**

```
use...

public function testBuild(Request $request)
   {
     $build = new PgBuild('myemail@test.us','mypassword');
     $title = $request->title;
     $file = $request->file;
     $method = 'file';
     $data = $build->uploadApp($file, $title, $method);
     return response()->json($data);
   }
```

**App\PgBuild@uploadApp:**

```
public function uploadApp($file, $title, $createMethod) {
        $link = "https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/apps";
        CURL_SETOPT($this->ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        CURL_SETOPT($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
        $post = array(
            "data" => array('create_method' => $createMethod, 'title' => $title),
            "file" => $file
        );
        CURL_SETOPT($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        $output = curl_exec($this->ch);
        $obj = json_decode($output);
        if (is_object($obj) && isset($obj->id)) {
            return json_encode($obj->id);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Thank you,